# deriving limited permutations of a text string

Tags: vb.net, list, permutation

This is getting to me, the result I desire are listed at the bottom; writing in vb.net 2012.  I've now reached the stupid point! (where I'll try anything because my logic has gone out the window!)  Suggestions?

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim strIn As String = "this is some meaningless text"
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}" & vbCrLf, strIn))
    Dim arStr As Array = Split(strIn, " "c)
    Dim word As String
    j = arStr.Length
    Do While i + j - 1 < j
        Do While j > 0
            word = String.Join(" ", arStr, i, j - i)
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}" & vbTab & "{1}" & vbTab & "{2}", word, i, j))
            i += 1
        Loop
        j -= 1
        i = 0
    Loop
```

From the above code what I want to see is this:

```
   '                       i   j
   '   this is some text   0   4
   '   this is some        0   3   
   '   is some text        1   3
   '   this is             0   2
   '   is some             1   2
   '   some text           2   2
   '   this                0   1
   '   is                  1   1
   '   some                3   1
   '   text                4   1
```

and I can't seem to format this.

Comment: Before starting on a task, you need to know the terminology of the area you are working with. Are you trying to split your sentence by words, and produce all possible combination thereof, excluding the empty set? Please confirm.

Comment: That was the reason for the example.  No, not all possible permutations of the words in the string.  In fact I'm looking at the file titles of books - I have a database of possible authors (and series) so I'm looking at adjoining words to be either author or series names.  Indeed some of the authors names are 6+ "words" long  examining those possibilities is realistic.  The problem I'm having is that the authors name may be anywhere in the file name.

Comment: Consider using a %LIKE% filter instead. This sounds like a typical problem though - if you come up with an efficient solution to it - you'd be like Google.

Comment: That is neither an answer nor a suggestion appropriate to the problem presented.

Answer (score 0):

What is the i column counting?  I mean what are you wanting it to count?  Not to oversimplify but j just looks like a count of the split words for that iteration.

Can you change j and i to meaningful names?  That might help.

Comment: Thanks Timmer.  No, I really can't they're just "markers" for which part of the string I'm trying to pick up.  I wrote it the way I did (in the example) hoping that I'd be able to see how to set the loop and indexes but I'm not seeing it.  (( and feeling really DUMB!! ))  "I" would be the (zero origin) of the first word, where "J" is the number of words to "pick up"

Comment: This is interesting.  I'm trying to get my brain around the pattern you're trying to implement
1  1  1  0  1
1  1  1  0  0
0  1  1  0  1
1  1  0  0  0
0  1  1  0  0
0  0  1  0  1
..and so on.  Do you have a formula to go with this pattern?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this comment section wouldn't keep my formatting.  The 1's and zero's represent the words obviously.  Lay them out in rows of 5 across.

Comment: No, as I told Neolisk, the text is the file name of an ebook.  It'll look something like "Abrey Aimes - Ration 01 - The Long Way Home" (variations of the order are pretty endless as are the separators)

Comment: No, the text is the file name of an ebook.  looking like "Abrey Aimes - Ration 01 - The Long Way Home" (variations of order are pretty endless as are the separators)  What I'm trying to do is pick up the adjacent words, from longest (the entire string) to shortest (each individual word), then hitting that string against an array list to find the author and/or the series.  Since some authors names may be inside anothers name "Martin Hall" is included in "George Martin Hall" I need to look for the longer strings first.

Comment: Oddly, putting together the inverse, looking at the shorter string first went together in a couple of hours - for some illogical reason I can't get my head around doing this.  My comment was too long and then it griped about me taking too long to edit it ... argh!

Answer (score 0):

I knew this was going to be a simple set of loops, but for some reason logic was eluding me.  The following code does what I want it to.  My thanks to those who replied.

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim strIn As String = "this is some text"
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:25} {1}  {2}", strIn, i, j))
    Dim arStr As Array = Split(strIn, " "c)
    Dim word As String
    j = arStr.Length
    While j > 0
        While i + j < arStr.Length + 1
            word = String.Join(" ", arStr, i, j)
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:25} {1}  {2}", word, i, j))
            i += 1 'starting at ...
        End While
        i = 0
        j -= 1
    End While
End Sub
```

Getting older and having a low threshhold for frustrations with simple things do not help!